# Regex emit items containing less than 100 words?

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want a regex value that searches for the amount of words and selects all articles in a feed that are less than 100 words. Is this possible?

For example there are 3 RSS feed items. One of them contains 500 words while the others contain less than 100.

I need an expression that matches any item with less than 100 words?

Thanks

Comment: Define articles and feeds. If you are talking about something XML or the like, you probably want to use a proper parser to extract the parts you want, then you can use something to count the words. Simple regex would be `/^\W*(?:\w+(?:\W+|$)){0,100}$/`, but also depends on how you define "words".

Comment: I want an expression that says: if less than 100 words emit. If more than 100 words continue. I'm using Yahoo Pipes to work with the feed but need to filter items with less than 100 words in the description.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by word you mean `\w+` you can use a regex like:

`^\W*(?:\w+(?:\W+|$)){0,100}$`

Comment: The amount of words in description part of RSS feed. For any that are less than 100 words not to be in the finished pipe?

Comment: That regex will match only if the post has 0 to 100 "words". (On the other hand, I don't know what kind of regex yahoo pipes support. Enter it without the `//` slashes used for quoting. You can also try removing both `?:` that you see in there.)

Comment: I got it eventually with lots of searching: http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?m=mm&bn=pip-genDiscuss&tid=3124&mid=3125&tof=2&o=lp&rt=2&frt=2&off=1 Thanks all for your help!

Comment: @Mark: what you should do is put that comment in an actual answer and accept it, if it really does solve your issue.  Reason why you should do this is to let people know this problem is solved.  I came here because the question didn't show up as "answered".  Thanks.